# Render action from another controller Rails - Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes, render

I have a modal form on fundraisers/show for a new pledge for a fundraiser which I want to send back errors without redirecting. If a user isn't signed in then a sign-up/sign-in form is shown which will either create a new user or find if already existing. So in the pledges controller I have:

```
def create
    if current_user
    // do something
    elsif @user.save
    // do something else
    else
    // send back instance variables with errors
    render template: 'fundraisers/show'
    end
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"fundraisers"}
```

My routes:

```
resources :fundraisers do
// other stuff in here
end
```

And of course fundraisers/show.html.erb exists because that's the view with the modal on it.

I think maybe there is some conflict with post vs. get request for that show action but I don't know how to solve it. I tried manually adding a post route for fundraisers/show but I wasn't getting anywhere. Ideas?

Comment: have you tried something like this? `render 'fundraisers/show'`. Also i'am assuming that "fundraisers" is a controller, am i right?.

Comment: don't you have to give an id to show action

Comment: yes fundraisers is a controller - i tried different versions such as  render 'fundraisers/show' and render action: 'fundraisers/show'

Comment: maybe - that's a good point, i tried passing fundraiser in through passing in locals { fundraiser: @fundraiser } but that didn't work do you have another idea

Comment: What is the stacktrace of this error?